# How do i create a new column in pyspark where the row values are same?

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark

Right now i have a pyspark data frame as:

```
x_data  y_data
2.5      2.5
2.5      2.5
2.5      2.5
2.5      2.5
```

and the value I want in all rows is "Smith"

```
**How do I create a data frame like this using pyspark?**


x_data  y_data    Name
2.5      2.8      Smith
7.5      5.1      Smith
1.5      1.5      Smith
8.5      6.5      Smith
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `withColumn` to add a new literal column:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df2 = df.withColumn('Name', F.lit('Smith'))
```